# how to display data of text file in list view

Tags: visual-c++

i want to display data from

> text file

in list view and in tree view. root will be file name, but i dont know how to do it, the problem is with displaying text file data in list view, i don't know anything about that. 
text file data is very simple
it is just a square matrix of double values like:

> 21.06 34.06 5.0
>
> 12.78 45.25 6.9
>
> 12.89 45.98 5.5

in list view i want to display it.

Answer (score 1):

**Read a Text File**

```
listBox1->Items->Clear();
    try   
    {    
        String* textFile = String::Concat(windir,(S"\\mytest.txt"));                               
            StreamReader *reader=new  StreamReader(textFile);
        do
        {
            listBox1->Items->Add(reader->ReadLine());
        }   
        while(reader->Peek() != -1);
    }      

    catch (System::Exception *e)
    { 
        listBox1->Items->Add(e);
    }

}
```

**View File Information**

```
listBox1->Items->Clear();
 String* testfile = String::Concat(windir, (S"\\notepad.exe")); 
 FileInfo *pFileProps  =new FileInfo(testfile);

 listBox1->Items->Add(String::Concat(S"File Name = ", (pFileProps->get_FullName() )) );
 listBox1->Items->Add(String::Concat(S"Creation Time = ", (pFileProps->get_CreationTime() ).ToString()) );
 listBox1->Items->Add(String::Concat(S"Last Access Time = "  ,(pFileProps->get_LastAccessTime() ).ToString()) );
 listBox1->Items->Add(String::Concat(S"Last Write Time = ", (pFileProps->get_LastWriteTime() ).ToString()) );
 listBox1->Items->Add(String::Concat(S"Size = ", (pFileProps->get_Length() ).ToString()) );
```

For More INfo see [HERE](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307398)

For Tree view you can follow this [page](http://www.functionx.com/visualc/treeview/tvdlg1.htm)

Comment: i have already used explorer for that purpose i mean i have not drag and drop listbox so what will be the alternative? to use above code in that case